# Apache Nifi HBASE lookup

Tags: hbase, streaming, lookup, apache-nifi, data-ingestion

I am new on Apache Nifi

We create Nifi flow, which is consuming json data from kafka and the results are being sent to another kafka topic after enrichment. However HBase lookup does not return value of key. Instead it returns key, value pair like  `MapRecord[{SERIAL_NUM=123456789}]`. But I require only value as '123456789'.

I could not resolve this issue. can anybody help me about this topic?

I am sharing the output of my flow. We want to see value of "hbase_integid" as "123456789", but lookup service returns

`MapRecord[{SERIAL_NUM=123456789}]"`

How can we extract only value of SERIAL_NUM value ("**123456789**")??

```
[
  {
    "table" : SIEBEL.S_ASSET,
    "op" : Update,
    "hbase_integid" : **MapRecord[{SERIAL_NUM=123456789}]**,
    "op_type" : U,
    "op_ts" : 2018-04-02 05:48:35.055299,
    "current_ts" : 2018-04-02T08:48:40.071000,
    "pos" : 00000000020530642196,
    "before" : {
        "ROW_ID" : 1-G7B7EGF,
        "BILLACCT_ID" : ,
        "BILL_ACCNT_ID" : 1-G79GNWP,
        "BILL_PROFILE_ID" : 1-1FJHFB0,
        "INTEGRATION_ID" : 1-G79GU5K,
        "NAME" : ,
        "OWNER_ACCNT_ID" : 1-G79GEVV,
        "OWNER_CON_ID" : 1-G79GEW3,
        "PROD_ID" : 1-Q5B470,
        "PROMOTION_ID" : ,
        "PROM_INTEG_ID" : ,
        "PROM_ITEM_ID" : ,
        "PR_ACCNT_ID" : ,
        "PR_CON_ID" : No Match Row Id,
        "ROOT_ASSET_ID" : 1-G7B7EFI,
        "SERIAL_NUM" : ,
        "X_VF_MSISDN" : ,
        "X_VF_PERMISSONS" : 
    },
    "after" : {
        "ROW_ID" : 1-G7B7EGF,
        "BILLACCT_ID" : ,
        "BILL_ACCNT_ID" : ,
        "BILL_PROFILE_ID" : ,
        "INTEGRATION_ID" : ,
        "NAME" : ,
        "OWNER_ACCNT_ID" : ,
        "OWNER_CON_ID" : ,
        "PROD_ID" : ,
        "PROMOTION_ID" : ,
        "PROM_INTEG_ID" : ,
        "PROM_ITEM_ID" : ,
        "PR_ACCNT_ID" : ,
        "PR_CON_ID" : ,
        "ROOT_ASSET_ID" : ,
        "SERIAL_NUM" : ,
        "X_VF_MSISDN" : ,
        "X_VF_PERMISSONS" : 
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: `How can we extract only value of SERIAL_NUM value ("123456789")??` -- it's not clear is your question to `hbase` or to `nifi` ?

Comment: My queston related with Nifi, I am trying to enrich data using LookupRecord. Habse Lookup Services has been enabled to get value of the Key field.

Answer (score 1):

In case your are using LookupRecord processor, the documentation is somewhat misleading. Set up your processor as shown in the screenshot. Ensure the following two properties are set propery:

1. Record result contents must be set to 'Insert record fields'
2. Record update strategy should be set to 'Use property'
3. Lastly Result Recordpath must be set to `/` and not `hbase_integid` (This is a bug in documentation it seems)

Hope that helps!

[image]

Comment: Not sure what happened with the OP, but this is THE answer, at least it was for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Lookup Record is giving output as a MapRecord; you may need to use other processors subsequently to extract the value of SERIAL_NUMBER.

A working example is given below.

[image]

**HBase Lookup Configuration**

[image]

Once you have result from lookup, you can use 2 UpdateRecord processors to extract and update the value of SERIAL_NUM in the flow file.

**Update Record 1 configuration**

[image]

**Update Record 2 configuration**

[image]